# Export data into SPSS file (*.sav)

Tags: export, spss

Is there any solution to export data into SPSS (*.sav) files?
I have a web service with surveys, and result needed to be exported to different formats.
I cant find any solution for SPSS.
(in any language, free or non-free products - but need to execute on the server!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good library https://github.com/tiamo/spss.
It was updated, and works as a charm