# How to read & write .sav (SPSS) files using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, spss

There are several questions and answers discussing how to read or write `.sav` files:

- `Excel`-related (e.g., [How to open spss data files in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150586/how-to-open-spss-data-files-in-excel))
- `PHP`-related (e.g., [Export data into SPSS file (*.sav)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066035/export-data-into-spss-file-sav))
- `Python`-related (e.g., [Exporting to SPSS files in Python Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463763/exporting-to-spss-files-in-python-django))

Do you know how to approach this in `Node.js` (with or without native addons)?
I appreciate if you can share any links to related resources.

Comment: Everything is possible with nodejs. You just need to write some code...

Comment: Ok @JonasW., I updated to my question to specifically ask whether you know and what to share some useful resources.

Comment: Then, please go ahead and vote these questions for closing as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066035/export-data-into-spss-file-sav, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463763/exporting-to-spss-files-in-python-django, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150586/how-to-open-spss-data-files-in-excel. I think you're missing the point, but thanks for your feedback anyway.